# Time Spans for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Reservation System, How can I a lot a RoomStatus in a certain TimeSpan?

ex.

```
    ArrivalDate : 09-21-2011 4:00pm

    NumberOfHours : 3

    DepartureDate : 09-21-2011 7:00pm

    RoomNo : 10

    RoomStatus : Reserved
```

I want that RoomNo 10 has the Status of RESERVED only between 4:00 - 7:00 pm?

Do you have ideas?

I am using SQL Server 2008 and VS 2010

**EDIT**

```
***RESERVATION TABLE***
PK-ReservationNo       bigint   
FK-ReservationTypeID   int  
PK-ClientID            bigint
FK-RoomNo              int
NoOfPersons            int  
NoOfHours              int  
ArrivalDate        smalldatetime
DepartureDate      smalldatetime

***ROOM TABLE***
PK-RoomNo           int
FK-RoomTypeNo       int
FK-RoomStatusId     int
```

Comment: With some kind of StartTime / EndTime pair (both `datetime`) on the record...

Comment: Yes, the Arrival and Departure time is the In and Out.. 

How can I say that 7:00pm onwards, room 10 is not reserved?

Comment: What does your data table look like? Do you want a query that for example gives you all the "free" rooms in a given time-span?

Comment: @Magnus, yes! that is what I want! Wait for me to edit my question and post all tables, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your query like this;

```
if datediff(hour, ArrivalDate, DepartureDate) > NumberOfHours 
update('Empty') 
else
update ('Reserved')
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE DateDiff(hour, ArrivalDate, DepartureDate) > NoOfHours

Is this correct?

Comment: But I wthink that is not that correct, because I want to see that from 7:00pm onwards, Room10 is still available. It is not available only between 4:00-7:00pm

Comment: your question is not clean. i guess you want to run this query what ever u want. so we need to CurrentTime and we could create this query:    CurrentTime=09-21-2011 10:00pm  if DATEDIFF(hour, ArrivalDate, CurrentTime)>NumberofHours and DATEDIFF(hour, DeparturDate, CurrentTime)>0 then ROOMISFREE else ROOMISFULL

Comment: I already figured the answer for this! I used the BETWEEN command! :) 
WHERE   (Reservation.ArrivalDate BETWEEN '2011-09-21 6:00:00' AND '2011-09-21 13:00:00') OR
        (Reservation.DepartureDate BETWEEN '2011-09-21 6:00:00' AND '2011-09-21 13:00:00')

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = '2011-01-01 12:00'
DECLARE @EndDate   DateTime = '2011-01-01 15:00'

--Free rooms between 12:00 and 15:00
SELECT *
FROM Room
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM 
      Reservation 
    WHERE 
      ((ArrivalDate > @StartDate AND ArrivalDate < @EndDate) OR
      (DepartureDate > @StartDate AND DepartureDate < @EndDate))) AND
      Reservation.FK-RoomNo = Room.PK-RoomNo)
```

Comment: Wait for a moment, i will be trying for this! :)
BTW, the startdatetime and enddatetime will be coming from VS2010

Comment: What do you mean by FREEROOMS BET 12:00-15:00?
I want to see all rooms available, except for one room that have the reservation of 12:00-15:00..

My hotel was a hostel btw!